# React Native - send image from local cache to firebase storage

Tags: react-native, firebase-storage

With React Native on Android I am trying to send the image profile of the user from local cache to a firebase storage bucket. If I send it as `blob` or `Uint8Array`, when I open the image on firebase I get the error `The image "https://firebasestorage<resto of url here>" cannot be displayed because it contain errors`. If I send it as `base64 data url`,it does not upload to the bucket and I get the message `Firebase Storage: String does not match format 'base64': Invalid character found`. I have tested the base64 data url with a decoder and it works. How can I get this to work, either as blob, Uint8Array or base64?. Here is the code:

**As blob**

```
let mime = 'image/jpeg';
getFile(imageUri)
  .then(data => {
    return new Blob([data], { type: mime });
  })
  .then(blob => {
    return imageRef.put(blob, { contentType: mime });
  })

async function getFile(imageUri) {
  let bytes = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(imageUri);
  return Promise.resolve(bytes);
}
```

**As Uin8Array**

```
let mime = 'image/jpeg';
getFile(imageUri)
  .then(data => {
    return imageRef.put(data, { contentType: mime });
  })


async function getFile(imageUri) {
  let bytes = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(imageUri);
  const imageBytes = new Uint8Array(bytes.length);
  for ( let i = 0; i < imageBytes.length; i++) {
    imageBytes[i] = bytes.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return Promise.resolve(imageBytes);
}
```

**As base64 data url**

```
imageBase64Url = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAADCAIAAADZSiLoAAAAF0lEQVQI12P8//8/AwMDAwMDEwMMIFgAVCQDA25yGkkAAAAASUVORK5CYII=";
return imageRef.putString(imageBase64Url, 'data_url');
```

**The URI**

I retrieve the uri from this object:

```
Object {
    "cancelled": false,
    "height": 60,
    "type": "image",
    "uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FMCC_Project-ee81e7bd-82b1-4624-8c6f-8c882fb131c4/ImagePicker/6ec14b33-d2ec-4f80-8edc-2ee501bf6e92.jpg",
    "width": 80,
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found at least two problems with the way I was trying to retrieve the picture and send it to the Firebase bucket:

1) When retrieving the image from memory and trying to send it as `blob` to the bucket, `FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(imageUri)` was returning for some reason a corrupted file

2) Instead when trying to save the image to Firebase bucket as `base64`, the problem seems to be with firebase, since not even the very same examples provided here https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files were working.

The solution:

We retrieved the image from local cache with `XMLHttpRequest`instead of Expo's `FileSystem`, and saved it to Firebase bucket as `blob`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import firebase from './firebase';

export default async function saveImage(picture, uid) {
  const storageRef = firebase
    .storage('gs://*<bucket-here>*')
    .ref(uid + '/' + 'profile-picture.jpeg');

  const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
      resolve(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.onerror = function(e) {
      console.log(e);
      reject(new TypeError('Network request failed'));
    };
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.open('GET', picture.uri, true);
    xhr.send(null);
  });

  const metadata = {
    contentType: 'image/jpeg',
  };

  return (downloadURL = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      storageRef.put(blob, metadata).then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL => {
          resolve(downloadURL);
        });
      });
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
  }));
}
```